# Creating Custom IconFactory in Gtkmm

Tags: c++, linux, gtkmm

I have a small application, where I want to create some buttons, toolbars, etc. but I do not want to use a pre-existing GTK icon theme, I want to create my own. So I looked for tutorials and whatnot, but as it turned out, it was not very well discussed online. So I tried to do something on my own:

Header File:

```
#include <gtkmm.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <errno.h>

class IconFactoryBuilder
{
public:
    IconFactoryBuilder();

    ~IconFactoryBuilder();

    void RegisterNewIcons(std::string pPath);

private:

    Glib::RefPtr<Gtk::IconFactory> mCustomFactory;
};
```

Cpp File:

```
#include <IconFactoryBuilder.h>

IconFactoryBuilder::IconFactoryBuilder() {
    mCustomFactory = Gtk::IconFactory::create();
}

IconFactoryBuilder::~IconFactoryBuilder() {
}

void IconFactoryBuilder::RegisterNewIcons(std::string pPath) {

    Glib::RefPtr<Gtk::IconSet> iconSet = Gtk::IconSet::create();
    Gtk::IconSource someSource;
    try{
        Gtk::Image  *someImage=Gtk::manage(new Gtk::Image(pPath+"appbar.at.png"));
        someImage->set_pixel_size(Gtk::IconSize(48));
        someSource.set_pixbuf(someImage->get_pixbuf());
        someSource.set_size(Gtk::ICON_SIZE_DIALOG);
        someSource.set_size_wildcarded();
    }
    catch(const Glib::Exception &ex) {
        std::cerr << "An error occurred while opening the icon file!" << strerror(errno) << std::endl;
    }
    catch(...) {
        std::cerr << "Unknown Error!" << std::endl;
    }
    iconSet->add_source(someSource);
    const Gtk::StockID somestock("MyNewIcon");
    Gtk::Stock::add(Gtk::StockItem(somestock, "somelabel"));
    mCustomFactory->add(somestock, iconSet);
    mCustomFactory->add_default();
}
```

But now I am quite stuck, because I do not really know how to call this new icon I have created. I also do not know if the above written code is enough to actually find the icon or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You created an icon factory... *factory*?

;-)

The serious answer to your question is that you don't need `Gtk::IconFactory`. Unfortunately the GTK 2 documentation doesn't tell you that it's unnecessary. What you do need is the [freedesktop.org Standard Icon Naming Specification](http://standards.freedesktop.org/icon-naming-spec/icon-naming-spec-latest.html). Create your icons, give them simple names, organize according to the directory structure described there, install it to the appropriate place, and your icons will "just work" when you create a `Pixbuf` or `Image` using the `...from_icon_name()` functions. ([example: `Gtk::Image::set_from_icon_name()`](http://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm/unstable/classGtk_1_1Image.html#a69bb4a5ee7299f6b373edc95989bf4f4))

Here is a page from the Gnome developer wiki on how to provide your own icons: 
http://developer.gnome.org/integration-guide/stable/icons.html.en

And here is a page from a tutorial I wrote about installing custom icons: http://ptomato.name/advanced-gtk-techniques/html/desktop-file.html

Comment: I did not understand your answer, to be honest. Of course I would not take all this trouble if stock icons is what I wanted to use. I need to create my own stock, with my own names. It is for a special purpose application, where the popular icon set does not meet the need.

Comment: So you want to replace the Gnome "open", "close", etc. icons with your own "open", "close" icons? Or you want to create your own icons e.g. "floop" and "greeble" which stand for actions in your application?

Comment: The latter one :) And I think I forgot to mention, I am using GTK3. The reason I cannot do the styling of the buttons using CSS is that I did not care to name a lot of the buttons and just created them by stock macros and standard GTK responses. But that was just for testing. Now I need to create specialized icons, which are normally not covered in standard icon sets.

Comment: The former is called an "icon theme". The latter is just installing application icons. For both, you need to use the Standard Icon Naming Specification. I will edit the answer.